# DB2 AS400 Java function always returns same value

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange, user-defined-functions

I am writing a user defined function to DB2 on AS/400 in Java and the strangest thing happen..
I am always getting the same result from the function even when i am changing it, even if i am dropping it and create it again and even when i specify NOT DETERMINISTIC..
Does any one have ever encountered a behavior like that?

Comment: stupid question: you are working in the same environment as your are testing?

Comment: no i am developing under windows and testing under AS400..
I'm constantly renaming the class for testing purposes..

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your create function command as well as a copy of the Java method header?

Comment: Though i think its quite irrelevant -

CREATE FUNCTION fnc()
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
FENCED
LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
NOT DETERMINISTIC
EXTERNAL NAME 'class.method'
EXTERNAL ACTION

JAVA:

public static java.lang.String fnc() {
 return "OK";
}

Comment: I thought I would see something stand out, but I don't.  Sorry, I have no answer for you. :-(

Comment: Thanks anyway... I will update after i'll contact with IBM support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Apparently this behavior only happens when i run queries from AS/400's STRSQL...
Queries outside of the AS/400 environment returns expected results.